# How do I transfer data from excel into 3D array in python, with X being latitude, Y longitude and Z representing depth?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a problem transferring data from an excel file into a 3D array. The different variables of data is latitude, longitude and depth of an area in western norway. The plan is to later have a reinforcement learning algorithm use this map of a 3D array to learn navigate the area at sea, i.e. where the depth is positive. We're essentially in the first step of making an automated route-planner.

This is the code I've used so far, which seems to create 3 different arrays, with the number of elements in the excel file used as rows for each individual one.

```
   import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file_loc = "excel1.xlsx"
Lat = pd.read_excel(file_loc,sheet_name='Sheet2', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="A")
long = pd.read_excel(file_loc,sheet_name='Sheet2', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="B")
Depth = pd.read_excel(file_loc,sheet_name='Sheet2', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols="C")

treD_array = np.array([[[Lat], [long]], [Depth]])

print(treD_array)
```

And this is what I get as an output;

VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
treD_array = np.array([[[Lat], [long]], [Depth]])
[list([[       60.262092
0      60.262092
1      60.262092
2      60.262092
3      60.262092
4      60.262092
...          ...
23973  60.444314
23974  60.444314
23975  60.444314
23976  60.444314
23977  60.444314

[23978 rows x 1 columns]], [        5.12317
0      5.123893
1      5.124616
2      5.125339
3      5.126063
4      5.126786
...         ...
23973  5.277191
23974  5.277915
23975  5.278638
23976  5.279361
23977  5.280084

[23978 rows x 1 columns]]])                 list([        27.47
0       42.26
1       60.70
2       81.17
3      100.91
4      118.34
...       ...
23973  187.83
23974  155.94
23975  104.80
23976   74.50
23977   54.84

```
                                         [23978 rows x 1 columns]])]
```

Where I do not understand the warning at all.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the columns as dataframes. In order to generate an `np.array` you have to convert them to list first:

```
treD_array = np.array([Lat.iloc[:,0].tolist(), long.iloc[:,0].tolist(), Depth.iloc[:,0].tolist()])
```

Comment: Thank you! Regarding the output I'm getting, is it still represented as three columns, and not three rows? [[ 60.262092  60.262092  60.262092 ...  60.444314  60.444314  60.444314]
 [  5.123893   5.124616   5.125339 ...   5.278638   5.279361   5.280084]
 [ 42.26      60.7       81.17     ... 104.8       74.5       54.84    ]]

Comment: Actually these are not three columns nor three rows, are three lists enclosed in one list

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this warning because of your syntax for creating your numpy array.

I think you are trying to build a numpy array that contains lists in its first column, with columns structured like ["coords", "Z"], with "coords" being lists containing ["lat", "lon"]. This should be avoided and it is best practice to use a structure like ["lat", "lon", "Z"] (which is why you are receiving this warning).

As @imburningbabe indicated, you could convert the dataframes returned by `pd.read_excel()` to lists.

I would suggest a more direct method of reading all data in a single dataframe, then converting to numpy array:

```
treD_dataframe = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='Sheet2', na_values=['NA'], usecols="A:C")

treD_array = treD_dataframe.to_numpy()

print(treD_array)
```